# audiotrack, how to skip wave header noise?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that plays .wav files by audiotrack class in static mode, but i can't figure out how to skip the wave header, here is the code i've done so for, i cant see whats wrong with it! anyone knows how to skip the header?
Thanks!

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
AudioTrack player;
int minBufferSize = 200000;
int waveHeader = 44;
byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufferSize -waveHeader];
InputStream is;
public TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    player = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crash);
    try {is.read(buffer, waveHeader, minBufferSize);} catch (IOException e)      {e.printStackTrace();}
    try {is.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    player.write(buffer, 0, minBufferSize);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playDrums();
        }});
}

public void playDrums(){
    player.play();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [read documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

> The first byte read is stored into element `b[off]`, the next one into `b[off+1]`, and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to `len`. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes will be stored in elements `b[off]` through `b[off+k-1]`, leaving elements `b[off+k]` through `b[off+len-1]` unaffected.

In other words the parameter `off` does not skip those bytes from the input stream, but instead stores them with an offset in the provided array.

To skip bytes from the input, you can either use [`skip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)):

```
try {is.skip(waveHeader);} catch (IOException e)               {e.printStackTrace();}
try {is.read(buffer, 0, minBufferSize);} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Or read the wave header in another buffer:

```
byte[] header = new byte[waveHeader];
try {is.read(header);} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
try {is.read(buffer, 0, minBufferSize);} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

After all you probably need the wave header in order to properly interpret the data (eg. is the data 1 or 2 bytes per sample, sampling rate, number of channels, ...)